# SIgned apk not running on my MOTO G mobile

Tags: android, motorola

I have created an android app in android studio and it is running well on emulator as well as on my mobile. I created its signed apk file. Then I send this generated "app-release.apk" file to my mobile and when I tried to install this, it shows me message that "App not installed". To confirm that my app-release.apk file is correct I tried to install it on some other cell where it get installed successfully.

I googled it a lot I have reset app preferences from settings of my mobile and also enabled installation of apps from unknown resources but still I am stucked.

Please suggest me some solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Please use adb to install the app, and post the installation log. Without it, we can't really help.

Comment: Does your release app use same certificate as dev?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the app from your Moto G mobile first then try installing the .apk.

Make sure that you uninstall the app "for all users".